# Design a Turing machine that calculates the parity of a binary number

Tags: binary, turing-machines, parity

so I have this problem given to me at my university, and I'm really lost about it, I don't know if you can help me cause this is not strictly code, I think I have to doit with digrams and tables by hand.

So, the problem is to design a Turing machine that calculates the parity of a binary number. If the number of 1's is pair add a 0 at the end, if it is unpair add a 1 at the end.

Example

```
a) 001001 -> 0010010

b) 101010 -> 1010101
```

Hoping you can help me, thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck with your attempts? Do you know how to build a DFA that accepts even or odd binary strings? If so, you can adapt that DFA into this Turing Machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input: a string `x` of binary digits

Output: `xd` where `d` id `0` if `#1(x)` is even and `1` if `#1(x)` is odd, where `#1(x)` is the number of instances of 1 in `x`.

Design: we will scan the string from left to right, keeping track of the parity of the number of instances of 1 seen so far. When we run out of input, we will see which state we are in, write the corresponding final digits, and then halt-accept.

Implementation:

```
q    t    q'   t'   d      comment

q0   0    q0   0    right  see a zero, stay in state and keep looking
q0   1    q1   1    right  see a one, now we've seen odd number, keep looking
q0   B    ha   0    same   ran out after seeing even number

q1   0    q1   0    right  see a zero, stay in state and keep looking
q1   1    q0   1    right  see a one, now we've seen an even number, keep looking
q1   B    hA   1    same   ran out after seeing odd number
```

Comment: Thanks! now I understand it too